# Selenium with python keeps on getting timedout even after I have manually set a really high timeout value

Tags: python, selenium, timeout

I am trying to use `webdriver.Firefox()` in my project. My firefox version is 54.0 and selenium version is 3.4.3.

I have tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

but this gives an error message

```
timeout: timed out
```

while opening the browser in less than a second so this definitely isn't a timeout issue. I have tried manually setting the timeout as,

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(timeout=100000)
```

Now it works fine at times but gives time out during opening browser and sometimes and sometimes gives time out while making a request even when the time taken for that request was very less, maybe around 2 seconds or less.

Is there an obvious problem here?

This is the full stacktrace

```
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/hackerearth/webapps/django/mycareerstack/apps/functional_tests/sprints/test_sprint_registration.py in <module>()
     24 
     25 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 26     unittest.main()

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in __init__(self, module, defaultTest, argv, testRunner, testLoader, exit, verbosity, failfast, catchbreak, buffer)
     92         self.testLoader = testLoader
     93         self.progName = os.path.basename(argv[0])
---> 94         self.parseArgs(argv)
     95         self.runTests()
     96 

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in parseArgs(self, argv)
    147             else:
    148                 self.testNames = (self.defaultTest,)
--> 149             self.createTests()
    150         except getopt.error, msg:
    151             self.usageExit(msg)

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc in createTests(self)
    153     def createTests(self):
    154         if self.testNames is None:
--> 155             self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromModule(self.module)
    156         else:
    157             self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc in loadTestsFromModule(self, module, use_load_tests)
     63             obj = getattr(module, name)
     64             if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, case.TestCase):
---> 65                 tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
     66 
     67         load_tests = getattr(module, 'load_tests', None)

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc in loadTestsFromTestCase(self, testCaseClass)
     54         if not testCaseNames and hasattr(testCaseClass, 'runTest'):
     55             testCaseNames = ['runTest']
---> 56         loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
     57         return loaded_suite
     58 

/home/hackerearth/webapps/django/mycareerstack/apps/functional_tests/sprints/test_sprint_registration.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      7 
      8     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
----> 9         super(RegistrationLandingPageTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     10         user = self.get_user()
     11         self.single_phase_hack = self.get_single_phase_hackathon()

/home/hackerearth/webapps/django/mycareerstack/apps/functional_tests/sprints/utils.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      6     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      7         super(SprintFunctionalTestCase, self).__init__(
----> 8             *args, **kwargs)
      9         user = self.get_user()
     10         self.login(user)

/home/hackerearth/webapps/django/mycareerstack/apps/functional_tests/utils.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     26     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     27         super(HEFunctionalTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
---> 28         self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(timeout=10000)
     29         self.homepage = 'http://localhost:8000'
     30         self.keys = Keys

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, firefox_options, log_path)
    150                 command_executor=executor,
    151                 desired_capabilities=capabilities,
--> 152                 keep_alive=True)
    153 
    154         # Selenium remote

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector)
     96             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
     97                           DeprecationWarning)
---> 98         self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
     99         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    100         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    186         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    187                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 188         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    189         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    190             response = response['value']

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    252 
    253         params = self._wrap_value(params)
--> 254         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    255         if response:
    256             self.error_handler.check_response(response)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.pyc in execute(self, command, params)
    462         path = string.Template(command_info[1]).substitute(params)
    463         url = '%s%s' % (self._url, path)
--> 464         return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
    465 
    466     def _request(self, method, url, body=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.pyc in _request(self, method, url, body)
    486             try:
    487                 self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
--> 488                 resp = self._conn.getresponse()
    489             except (httplib.HTTPException, socket.error):
    490                 self._conn.close()

/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc in getresponse(self, buffering)
   1134 
   1135         try:
-> 1136             response.begin()
   1137             assert response.will_close != _UNKNOWN
   1138             self.__state = _CS_IDLE

/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc in begin(self)
    451         # read until we get a non-100 response
    452         while True:
--> 453             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    454             if status != CONTINUE:
    455                 break

/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc in _read_status(self)
    407     def _read_status(self):
    408         # Initialize with Simple-Response defaults
--> 409         line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
    410         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
    411             raise LineTooLong("header line")

/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in readline(self, size)
    478             while True:
    479                 try:
--> 480                     data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
    481                 except error, e:
    482                     if e.args[0] == EINTR:

timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Post the full terminal output (stacktrace)

Comment: You can set timeout using the driver.set_page_load_timeout(60);

Comment: I have added the stacktrace

Comment: `GeckoDriver` version & `Python` version please? Consider showing your code block as well. Thanks